# Get the token of a closed uncreated generic method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I'm using `MethodBuilder.SetMethodBody()` to emit the method instead of using the built in `ILGenerator`. The reason is mainly more control with exception handling information, and generally to have more control over the opcodes emitted.

In all situations where I need to emit a call to a method I'm calling `ModuleBuilder.GetMethodToken()` and it works fine except for when I need to `call` a closed generic method that is uncreated (withing the same dynamic module). It's throwing a `NotSupportedException:Specified method is not supported.`.

Of course `MethodBuilder.TokenMetadata` doesn't work because the method is uncreated, and this leaves me with nothing else to try.

So the question is, how do I get the token to use in my custom emitting of a `call` opcode to this generic method?

**Edit:** I found out that the built in `ILGenerator.EmitCall` gets the token through a call to an internal method that accepts a bool, the generator passes false sometimes. However, `MethodBuilder.GetMethodToken()` always passes true to the same internal method. It seems to be it, but since internal methods are out of my reach, there has to be another way?

I'm actually thinking about using reflection to get and invoke the method manually if there's no other way.

**Edit:** Indeed, invoking the internal method (which is `ModuleBuilder.GetMethodTokenInternal` btw) through reflection with false as a parameter does solve the issue. But I don't believe that there isn't a normal way of getting the token, since the `SetMethodBody` needs it if you manually call to a generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is invoking the internal method through reflection and pass it the required args.

```
// If the to be called method is generic...
var methodInfo = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder")
                    .GetTypeInfo()
                    .DeclaredMethods
                    .Where((method) => method.Name == "GetMethodTokenInternal" && method.GetParameters().Length == 3)
                    .First();
int token = 
    (int)methodInfo.Invoke(_moduleBuilder, new object[] { closedGenericMethod, null, false });
```

But I actually use a delegate to make things faster after the first call.